# Moving lots of data between a Linux server and a MacBook: what is the fastest way possible?

Tags: time-machine, backup, unix

Time Machine restoring is getting on my nerves.

Last time my Mac refused to boot it took me a few **days** to restore the image from my backup server to my Mac. Bear in mind that all related hardware is capable of saturating the gigabit Ethernet link (as discovered when I am transferring files over WebDAV which is an ultra low overhead protocol,) and my Mac have just 480GB of retrofitted SSD.

So, if I am ditching Time Machine (which works over AFP protocol) what is the fastest way to transfer lots of files, the entire backup in this case, from and to the backup server? Note that I don't trust Linux's HFS+ driver.

If the issue is on the Linux side, please move this question to Ask Ubuntu or SuperUser if appropriate.

---

Information that may be useful:

My MacBook Pro is the 2012 model (13-inch non-Retina) with a retrofitted 480GB Intel 520 Series SSD.

Here is my backup server, if you suspect hardware bottleneck and/or expansion card slot availability:

> - MoBo: Asus P5BV-C (one PCIe 1.0 x4 slot open, so you can suggest me to get some new hardware to help data copying)
> - Disk drives: Western Digital Green 6TB + Kingston V300 SSD 60GB (configured as bcache, like Intel SR, effectively a Linux version of Fusion Drive)
> - NIC: onboard Marvell server-grade NIC, backed by PCIe (not saturated - this is the problem)
> - OS: Ubuntu Linux 15.04 (Linux kernel 3.19)

Comment: The answer to most transfer protocol questions is use rsync - How slow is the TM restore?

Comment: @Mark It takes a day in a sunny day and a few if rainy. That is the problem.

Comment: Is the server remote? I assume so by your previous comment, but would like to be sure.

Comment: @agentroadkill It is not remote in the sense I cannot physically reach it - it is located just under my workbench, and I can reach over and plug some cords onto it should I feel like it.

Comment: @MaxthonChan Difference due to weather sounds like a hardware issue not protocol

Comment: @Mark it is not "difference based on weather", the "sunny day or rainy" means "a good day or a bad one".

Comment: If you can physically plug the MacBook into the server, you could absolutely connect the two physically. The obvious choice is a network switch and a thunderbolt adapter, then copy from the server to the MacBook as you have been. If you are totally desperate to get this done as quickly as possible, I might suggest a [PCI-e to Thunderbolt adapter]:(http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1039491), which would allow you to start the MacBook in target disk mode, then copy the files from the server down.

Comment: @agentroadkill That would run into my aforementioned non-trust of Linux kernel HFS+ driver. Also Linux's version of CoreStorage, disk mapper (`dm`), does not parse CoreStorage volumes. By the way, I am already copying data over a wired gigabit link, and due to the speed of SATA 6Gb/s and the spinning platters on the Linux box being the next bottleneck after GbE link, going 10GbE is pointless and costly.

Comment: Create an exFAT partition and copy to that? If you're getting full gigabit speeds, I don't know that you have very much opportunity to grow...

Comment: @agentroadkill Not really gonna work: where should I put the exFAT partition? How to access on the other machine? And how to transfer the data?

Comment: Well since you don't trust the Linux HFS+ driver, you'd create a boot partition for Mac OS (HFS+) and a data partition on your boot drive (exFAT). You back up the data and transfer it at your leisure, just don't delete anything on the booth partition

Comment: I'm not particularly thrilled with Time Machine, but I haven't seen it be that slow.  However, I rarely restore an entire system.  If and when my Mac gets flaky, I generally install a clean OS and then bring in users, apps, and settings with Migration assistant.  Last time (one TB SSD half full) took less than an hour for the OS install and less than an hour for the migration over USB.

Comment: rsync doesn't offer much benefit when you have to transfer _everything_.